# Having trouble checking out the git repo for streamingkit

Tags: ios, xcode, git, streaming

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit.git

I get errors when trying to grab the repo via git.

```
Cloning into 'StreamingKit'...
warning: templates not found /usr/local/share/git-core/templates
remote: Counting objects: 1435, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (831/831), done.
remote: Total 1435 (delta 799), reused 1045 (delta 555)
Receiving objects: 100% (1435/1435), 4.54 MiB | 700.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (799/799), done.
'hecking connectivity... fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/Icon
fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
Unexpected end of command stream
```

I get missing files when I download the ZIP file from the git page.

```
When trying to compile either example:
ld: library not found for -lStreamingKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried forking the repo and cloning it from your own account?

Answer (score 0):

Launch ExampleApp via StreamingKit.xcworkspace